# Adding the multiples of two ranges together gives me a different number depending how its coded

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning some basics in `Python 3`. I tried cleaning up the code a little bit and it gave me different numbers.

At first I thought it was because the `or` statement was giving me the output of multiples of 3 or 5, excluding numbers like 15, 30, 45, but my or statement in the 2nd example gives me a larger number, so it's clearly not omitting any.

> Goal: compute all multiples of 3, 5 that are less than 100

Attempt1

```
total4 = 0
for i in range(1,100):
    if i % 3 == 0: 
        total4 += i
total5 = 0
for i in range(1,100):
    if i % 5 == 0: 
        total5 += i
total6 = total4 + total5
print(total4)#1683
print(total5)#950
print(total6)#2633
```

Attempt2

```
total4 = 0
for i in range(1,100):
    if i % 3 or 1 % 5 == 0:
           total4 += i
print(total4)
#3267
```

Comment: Your first attempt counts any multiple of 15 twice (once in the first loop and once in the second). Your second attempt is checking `i % 3`, not `i % 3 == 0`, and it is checking `1 % 5 == 0`, not `i % 5 ==0`.

Comment: @AaronLFeeney What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to count how many numbers between 1 and 100 are divisible by 3 or 5?

Comment: @AaronL.Feeney Just to be clear: Is your goal to count those multiples or sum them? Because your code seems to be adding them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second attempt doesn't do what you intended, for two reasons.

First, the typo in `1%5 == 0`. I suppose you intended `i` instead of `1`. However, correcting that will give `total4==3582`, which is still not what you expected.

This is because you wrote the if-statement not as you intended. `i%3 or i%5 == 0` means "True if at least one of `i%3` or `i%5==0` is true". (Note in computer science `or` nearly always mean "at least one of them is true.") To understand what "`i%3` is true", you should know that **all integers other than 0 is considered "true".**

So the correct condition for your if-statement is `i%3==0 or i%5==0`.

Well, that still gives a different value of `2318`. This is practically (the sum of multiples of 3 below 100) + (the sum of multiples of 5 below 100) - (the sum of multiples of 15 below 100). ([Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)!)

Your first code ('Attempt1') doesn't calculate the sum of multiples of 15 below 100, only calculates (the sum of multiples of 3 below 100) + (the sum of multiples of 5 below 100), so if you want to produce a same result as your second code ('Attempt2'), you will need another variable to accumulate the sum of multiples of 15.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt condition should be something like:

```
    if (i % 3 == 0) or (i % 5 == 0):
```

That is, the ==0 condition shall be applied twice, and I bet 1 % 5 in your code was a typo.

You may want to print(i) inside the loop to debug which numbers are being counted.

Comment: As @khelwood stated before, the condition i % 3 it's the opposite to the one you want. For instance, if (i % 3) will be True if the result of i % 3 is different from 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have a little typo in your if condition in the second version. Instead of

```
if i % 3 or 1 % 5 == 0:
```

it probably should be this (note the change from `1` to `i` and using `== 0` in both parts)

```
if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
```

---

Furthermore, I'm not sure that you are getting the output you intend. Let me ilustrate the situation:

```
divisible_by_3_count = 0
divisible_by_3_sum = 0
divisible_by_5_count = 0
divisible_by_5_sum = 0
divisible_by_3_or_5_count = 0
divisible_by_3_or_5_sum = 0
divisible_by_3_and_5_count = 0
divisible_by_3_and_5_sum = 0

for i in range(1, 100):             # will not include the number 100
    if i % 3 == 0:
        divisible_by_3_count += 1
        divisible_by_3_sum += i
    if i % 5 == 0:
        divisible_by_5_count += 1
        divisible_by_5_sum += i
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:    # uses OR
        divisible_by_3_or_5_count += 1
        divisible_by_3_or_5_sum += i
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:   # uses AND
        divisible_by_3_and_5_count += 1
        divisible_by_3_and_5_sum += i

print(divisible_by_3_count)                          #   33
print(divisible_by_3_sum)                            # 1683
print(divisible_by_5_count)                          #   19
print(divisible_by_5_sum)                            #  950
print(divisible_by_3_or_5_count)                     #   46
print(divisible_by_3_or_5_sum)                       # 2318
print(divisible_by_3_and_5_count)                    #    6
print(divisible_by_3_and_5_sum)                      #  315

print(divisible_by_3_count + divisible_by_5_count)   #   52
print(divisible_by_3_sum + divisible_by_5_sum)       # 2633
```

The last option (the sum of 2 variables) might not really be accurate as some numbers are summed twice; for example the number `30` is already summed in `divisible_by_3_sum` and again in `divisible_by_5_sum`, that is why:

```
# 33 + 19 > 46
>>> (divisible_by_3_count + divisible_by_5_count) > divisible_by_3_or_5_count
True

# 1683 + 950 > 2318
>>> (divisible_by_3_sum + divisible_by_5_sum) > divisible_by_3_or_5_sum
True
```

I hope this helps you.